# Force require to check the current directory for a module

Tags: node.js, node-commander

I'm creating a command line application with Node. How can I make `require` check the current directory for the module?

For example, I want to run the command in the testing directory:

```
root@hello:~/projects/testing$ mycmd
```

And get the module which is in the `node_modules/` of that directory, rather than it using a global version.

```
var myModule = require("testing/mymodule");
```

Comment: Try `require("./testing/mymodule");`

Comment: @thefourtheye nope doesn't work already tried it.

Comment: Sorry, perhaps I misunderstood the question. Do you mean to say that you want to access a file which is in the `node_modules` directory?

Comment: Exactly, but inside the directory the command was run.

Comment: Can you please show the actual structure of the `node_modules`? Also, why don't you use the actual module installed there?

Comment: The structure is no different to a brand new npm init with one module installed, nothing fancy. So I don't know what you mean by that?

Comment: That is what I would like to do, but because my command is installed **globally**, its looking for the module **globally**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `process.cwd()` to find their current directory, I can then just get the dependencie from the `node_modules/` folder.

/usr/local/lib/node_modules/mycmd/index.js:

`require(process.cwd() + "/node_modules/request");`